# How to calculate the Azure Cosmos DB RU used in server side scripting

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

If I write a javascript store procedure in cosmos db and I loop through 1000 document and each doc is 1K size, does it cost me 1000 RU?

Comment: The easiest way is to find using the request charge response header.Every response from the Azure Cosmos DB service includes a custom header (x-ms-request-charge) that contains the request units consumed for the request

Answer (score 6, accepted):

RU calculation doesn't work like that (eg you cannot simply assume 1K doc x 1000 = 1000 RU).

The most accurate way of determining the cost of your stored procedure is to examine the RU charge, which is returned in the headers following the call to the stored procedure.

The header is `x-ms-request-charge` and is exposed via the returned headers in the SDK calls as well as raw REST calls.

In node/javascript, you'd make a call that looks something like:

```
client.executeStoredProcedure(sprocLink,params,options, function (err, doc, headers) {
  ...
})
```

You'd want to look at `headers['x-ms-request-charge']`.

Answer (score 1):

One of the answer as @David mentioned above.

However, inorder to calculate and estimate the pricing beforehand.Request Unit can be calculated based on the following factors,

(i) Data object schema and the size

(ii)Type of queries

(iii)Writes/Queries per second

(iv) Consistency level/indexing policy

Also you can use the **[Capacity Planner](https://www.documentdb.com/capacityplanner)** tool to calculate the Request Units needed.